# Change fragment by clicking on the nav_header_main

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on an Android application using navigation drawer activity.
Each different menu items are used to display their own fragment on my mainActivity.

When I open my drawer, I would like the drawer header (corresponding to the file nav_header_main.xml, with logo and 2 texts) to be clickable, and displaying then my HomeFragment().

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie, so the answer may seems obvious, but Ok, I finally found a solution :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

fun changeFragment (fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

// hamburger menu listener
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

// navigation header menu listener
    val headerLayout = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)

    val nav_drawer_header = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_header) as LinearLayout
    nav_drawer_header.setOnClickListener{
        changeFragment(HomeFragment())
        onBackPressed()
    }


override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> return true
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```